# M/d with Current Year format for DateFormatter

Tags: swift

i have a textfield bound to a date with dateformater the dateformat property is set to "M/d".  when i enter a string like 3/1 into the textfield it returns 3/1/2000.  how can i set it to default to the current year but with out having to type the year in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your date formatter's defaultDate using the start of the current year:

Create your custom date formatter

```
extension Formatter {
    static let monthDay: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/d"
        return dateFormatter
    }()
}
```

Then add a target for your textField for control event editing changed:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
```

Create a method to check every time the textField value changes if the text typed by the user can be parsed by your date formatter. Set the start of the current year as the defaultDate of your dateFormatter:

```
 @objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
    let defaultDate = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: year).date!
    Formatter.monthDay.defaultDate = defaultDate
    if let date = Formatter.monthDay.date(from: textField.text!) {
        print(date.description(with: .current))
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is no property on the dateformatter for this I have to extend or subclass?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1408312-defaultdate

Comment: Doh I’m sorry I see it now. That’s what I get for posting at 1am.

Comment: Not on that issue no. Thanks for your help